# IE stylesheet conditionals

Tags: html, css

Does it matter the order you have your style sheet for IE in. Below I'm using the standard conditional but for some reason when I override a style from my base.css in the ie.css its not getting overridden.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css"/>
```

Comment: If you switch the order, do the IE corrections work?

Comment: The order does matter.  Put your conditional after your base stylesheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Whichever class is encountered last will override all the ones before. Conditional IE styles should come after your base styles, else the base styles will overwrite the IE ones.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css"/>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you need to swap them. Stylesheets are processed in order, so the later they are in your source, the more priority a selector takes.